# TKINTER, images mix when multiple window launched

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

[IMAGE: --->ScreenShot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SATE.png)

[IMAGE: --->How it is meant to look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be4HY.png)

In the first hyperlink above i have attached a screenshot of the problem.

When running the windows which are connected by a button, the image on the window that is launched from the first window displays on the first window and not on the new window just opened.

At first I  thought that python might be getting confused because the file name is the same. (that wasn't the case as I  used a slightly different image with a different file name.

I  have tried so many ways and it just doesnt work.

Directly below this line is the code for the first window:

```
#----Main Menu----
root_menu = Tk()
root_menu.title("Warehouse Inventory Control System")
root_menu.configure(bg = "black")


photo = PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
photoLabel = Label(image=photo)
photoLabel.image = photo
photoLabel.grid(row=1, column=3,columnspan = 4, sticky = N)

Title_Screen = Label(root_menu,
                     text="Welcome to the SsangYong\n Warehouse Inventory        Control System",
                     fg="grey",
                     bg="black",
                     font="Helevetica 25 bold",
                     pady = "50",
                     padx = "50",
                     ).grid(row=2, column=3)


Search_Inventory = Button(root_menu,
                          text = "Search Inventory",
                          command=Search_Inventory,
                          fg = "Blue",
                          bg = "Grey",
                          bd = 2,
                          font="Helevetica 12 bold",
                          height = 1,
                          width = 50,
                          ).grid(row=16, column=3,pady = 25,padx = 25,)

Add_Stock = Button(root_menu,
                text = "Add New Items",
                command = Add_To_Database,
                fg = "Blue",
                bg = "Grey",
                bd = 2,
                font="Helevetica 12 bold",
                height = 1,
                width = 60,
                ).grid(row=15, column=3,pady = 25,padx = 25,)

Print_Report =  Button(root_menu,
                text = "Print Stock Report",
                fg = "Blue",
                bg = "Grey",
                bd = 2,
                font="Helevetica 12 bold",
                height = 1,
                width = 70,
                ).grid(row=17, column=3,pady = 25,padx = 25,)


Help_Button = Button(root_menu,
                     text = "Help",
                     command=Help_PDF,
                     fg = "Red",
                     bg = "Black",
                     height = "1",
                     bd = "2",
                     font = "Helevetica 20 bold",
                     width = "4",
                     ).grid(row=1, column=3,rowspan = 2, sticky= NE)
root_menu.mainloop()
```

and here is the code for the second window.

```
def Search_Inventory():
#---Search Window----
root_search = Tk()
root_search.title("Warehouse Inventory Control System")
root_search.configure(bg = "black")

#----Title displayed under the company logo on the first window----
Title_Screen = Label(root_search,
                     text="Warehouse Inventory Control System",
                     fg="grey",
                     bg="black",
                     font="Helevetica 25 bold",
                     pady = "50",
                     padx = "50",
                     ).grid(row=3, column=4)

#----Interactive Input Boxes for the User----

#----Label to Notify what is needed in the entry box----

PN_Info_Label = Label(root_search,
                    text = "Part Number:",
                    fg="white",
                    bg="black",
                    font="Helevetica 15 bold",
                    padx = 50,
                    ).grid(row=14, column=3, rowspan = 2)

#----Input Box for Part Number

PN_Display = StringVar()
Input_PartNumber = Entry(root_search,
                         textvariable=PN_Display,
                         fg = "blue",
                         font = "Helevtica 25 bold",
                         ).grid(row=14, column=4)

#----A button that will proceed to the next part of the program----

Search_Button = Button(root_search,
                       text = "Search Inventory",
                       fg = "Blue",
                       bg = "Grey",
                       bd = 2,
                       font="Helevetica 15 bold",
                       command=lambda:Search_Prod(PN_Display.get()),
                       height = 1,
                       width = 15,
                       ).grid(row=16, column=4,pady = 25,padx = 25,)

#----Information regarding how to enter the part number---
Info = Label(root_search,
             text="Please Use Capitals to Enter Part Number",
             fg= "red",
             bg = "black",
             font = "helevetica 12 bold",
             ).grid(row = 15, column = 4)
#----Adding the company logo to the first window----

photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
photoLabel = Label(image=photo)
photoLabel.image = photo
photoLabel.grid(row=1, column=4, pady = 10)

#----Linking the Help Document----

Help_Button = Button(root_search,
                     text = "Help",
                     command=Help_PDF,
                     fg = "Red",
                     bg = "Black",
                     height = "1",
                     bd = "2",
                     font = "Helevetica 20 bold",
                     width = "4",
                     ).grid(row=0, column=5, pady= 10,padx = 50, sticky = E)

#----Saying who the program was made by----

Credits = Label(root_search,
                text = "Created By: Me",
                fg = "White",
                bg = "Black",
                font = "Helevetica 10 underline",
                ).grid(row = 19, column = 5)
#To Make Sure that the window doesn't close
root_search.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it's appearing in the wrong window, it's because it has the wrong parent. Look closely at your code.

Comment: if by parent you mean stating the actual window in the code to display the image, I tried that and it still didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

In your question you show this for your "second window":

```
def Search_Inventory():
    #---Search Window----
    root_search = Tk()
    ...
    photoLabel = Label(image=photo)
```

There are two problems with the above code. For one, you're creating a second instance of `Tk`. You should not do this. A tkinter program should have exactly one instance of `Tk`. If you want additional windows you need to create instances of `Toplevel`.

The second problem is where you create the `Label` -- you are neglecting to give it a parent so it is probably defaulting to the original window. You need to change that last line to this:

```
photoLabel = Label(root_search, image=photo)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how do i add a parent to it?

Comment: @MikiAmeryk: the same way that you added a parent to every other widget that you create. `Label(root_search, image=photo)`

Comment: photo = PhotoImage(root_search, file="image.gif")
photoLabel = Label(image=photo)
photoLabel.image = photo
photoLabel.grid(row=1, column=4, pady = 10)

Comment: i always added it to the first line